# Wildfly 8.1 - Websockets in a Clustered Config?

Tags: apache, jboss, websocket, wildfly, ajp

I have a 2-node cluster setup using the standalone-full-ha.xml configuration on Wildfly 8.1.  I'm trying to open up a web socket connection through Apache HTTPD URL, but when I do I see the following error in my logs, and the web socket open fails with an error in JavaScript:

```
2014-07-28 15:58:52,675 ERROR [io.undertow.request] (default task-4) UT005023: Exception handling request to /WebSocketTest/hello: java.lang.IllegalStateException: UT000077: The underlying transport does not support HTTP upgrade
```

Is there any way to get such a configuration working in a clustered setup?  Or would I need to go to the specific app server port directly and bypass Apache HTTPD?

Answer (score 0):

what version of Apache httpd are you using? 
Web Sockets seem to be supported from 2.4 with [mod_proxy_wstunnel](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy_wstunnel.html)

also undertow's documentation states that [AJP does not support protocol upgrade](http://undertow.io/documentation/core/overview.html)